# On iOS, in a ViewController's viewDidLoad, the number of subviews is 0? Which method can show the populated number?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uiwindow

Using Xcode 4.3.2, starting a brand new Single View App, in ViewController's

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // ...

    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    NSLog(@"How many subviews %i", window.subviews.count);
}
```

The count is actually `0`... if I print out the number in a tap event handler, then I do see `1`, which is the main view of the app.  So I wonder how come in `viewDidLoad`,  `[subviews count]` is `0` and is there an init or begin method like `viewDidLoad` where it would print `1` already (no need to print it in the tap event handler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to NSLog the count of subviews in - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

viewDidLoad
Called after the controller’s view is loaded into memory.
viewDidAppear:
Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy.

Comment: so `viewDidLoad` didn't mean the main view is already loaded (or added)?

Comment: At `viewDidLoad:`, it has been loaded into memory.  The framework then calls `viewWillAppear:` to let you know it's going to put it into the window and `viewDidAppear:` when that's complete.